# How to enable/disable android wi-fi or bluetooth in intel xdk?

Tags: android, bluetooth, device, android-wifi, intel-xdk

Im just beginning with Intel XDK, I really need to know a way to change the mobile(WIFI GPS screen bright) settings through javascript(xdk or using any plugin or something) or even calling some java or other language block that would do this ...

If is there a way compatible with the exportations formats

Thank You

**EDIT**

> It seems to there be some lib for W8: Microsoft.WinJs that handle the
>   'low level functions' like those (enable disable).. I would want to
>   know if there is one MS's equivalent for Android Systems...
>
> Thank you again dudes

Answer (score 1):

I dont know but, may be these links could help you to some extent:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493102

http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493060

http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493063

However, I found this to work around bluetooth for windows 8:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/sample-application-bluetooth-peer-connection-sample

Further, If i come across something you want I will update my answer here. Njoy coding...!!!

Comment: Thank you for the help, but those top links I've already visited ^^ not exactly what I meant there, anyway thank you again. Im starting to guess the xdk can't do such that pretty, but the last one gave my eyes some hope > > It seems to be some lib for W8: Microsoft.WinJs that handle the 'low level function' ... it would be pretty to know if there is one like the MS's for Android Systems

Comment: @MauroDias Sorry, i wasnt able to help you, but I had started working on Intel XDK since last week only. I am really looking forward, when intel xdk includes almost all the funcionalities that a naive SDK provides, in its upcoming updates, because I loved working with it.. Anyways.. I will be updaing answer if i found any solution..

Comment: never mind, i'm all thankful about your interest... and like you I've just started with INTEL IDK , to be honest, yesterday was my first :D so we are together looking after this ... o/

Comment: @MauroDias You know... I am moving towards the belief that, not all the functionalities that a native platform provides in its API, `HTML5` would be able to support for now. Dont know whether, in future, we would be able to build apps completely free from platform dependencies, through `html5`.